# How does change of basis on linear transformation matrix work

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Wrestling with conversion of bases on a linear transformation.
According to the books, "In order to enable matrix multiplication to give us the result of some linear T applied to a vector v, we must make sure T and v are both expressed in a common basis. In that case, w = MT · v only makes sense if both vectors and all the columns of MT are expanded along that common basis."

I was trying to wrap my arms around this so I thought I'd start with a degenerate case and see how it plays out.

Ok, let's let the basis of a one dimensional space be (1)
Let the transformation be the identity transformation, so the matrix of transformation is [1]. Let's apply that to the vector (1):

[1]•(1)=(1)

Now let's see what happens if we change the basis to (2)

So according to the rule above, we view the transformation matrix as a list of column vectors, and translate each of those column vectors the new basis

That yields [1/2] for the transformed matrix.

Then we translate our vector to the new basis, which is (1/2). So the result is [1/2]•(1/2)=(1/4)

Which is not what the book guarantees
I'm sure it's something simple but I'm missing it

Comment: Solve [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) in $1$ dimension. You may find the $2$-dimensional case more instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see my mistake. You need to (1) *first* apply the transformation to each of the new basis vectors, then (2)  for each resulting basis vector change the basis to the new basis, then (3) augment those into a new transformation matrix. Then (4) apply that to the vector, expressed in the new basis

So in my example, 
Step 1. [1]x(2)=(2),
Step 2. change to the basis (2) which yields (1) in the new basis
Step 3. New transformation matrix is [1]
Step 4. The original vector (1) becomes (1/2) in the new basis. 
So the transformation in the new basis is 
[1]x(1/2)=(1/2) in the new basis, which translates to (1) in the original basis as expected

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of identity is the same in all  bases.

To ensure this in the present case ($1$-dimensional), consider the change of basis  matrix $P$: its columns are the components of the vectors in the new basis w.r.t. the old basis, i.e. it is the matrix $P=(1/2)$. On the other hand, the  formula to have the expression of a linear map in the new basis ($A'$) in function of its matrix in the old basis ($(A)$) is:
$$A'=P^{-1}AP.$$

Here, $P=(1/2)$, so $P^ {-1}=(2)$, and $$A'=(2)A(1/2)=(2)(1)(1/2)=(1).$$

Comment: The formula for the expression of the matrix of a linear map in a new basis? It is standard in all books on linear algebra, and not hard to prove. Thanks  for pointing the typos! Hopefully, I've fixed all of them.